# Pantone framebox in XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, color

I have my document in XeLaTeX.

I need to use `PANTONE` colors, so I choose `xespotcolor`.

MWE looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xespotcolor}
\usepackage{color}

\NewSpotColorSpace{PANTONE}
\AddSpotColor{PANTONE} {KINOVAR} {PANTONE\SpotSpace 200\SpotSpace U} {.09 .86 .5 .1}
\definecolor{kinovarCMYK}{cmyk}{.09,.86,.5,.1}

\begin{document}
\SetPageColorSpace{PANTONE}
\textcolor[spotcolor]{KINOVAR,1}{Pantone text.}

\textcolor{kinovarCMYK}{CMYK text.}

\fcolorbox{kinovarCMYK}{white}{Text in a CMYK box.}
\end{document}
```

I want to put a pantone-colored frame, but I cannot use `tikz` (AFAIK it is not compatible with `xespotcolor`) and don't know how to make `\fcolorbox` use pantone.

Comment: I contacted Apostolos Syropoulos, the author of `xespotcolor` package, and the updated version of `xelatex` works with `fcolorbox` now.

Comment: Version 2.0 of the xespotcolor package works just fine with the TikZ package.